# Quantum Games/Superiority of quantum strategies over probabilistic

Tags: quantum-information

In the paper **Multi-Player Quantum Games** by Hayden and Benjamin, there is a 3-player game in Fig 2.c where probabilistic classical players do better than quantum players. What does the words "do better" precisely mean here, and how this can be possible, when quantum strategies are "supersets" of classical probabilistic?

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0007038

Comment: Did you read and understand the paper? They probably define what "do better" means...

Comment: In which page? "do better" may mean all players together (as in Pareto-optimality) or each separately in an output profile. Anyway, does this example means (and how to see it from fig 2.c) that Quantum strategies may be worse then Probabilistic? How to actually calculate this for the game in Fig 2.c?

Comment: Giving weapons to both sides doesn't always make both sides happier: this paper considers games with potential competition, so it's conceivable that the nash equilibrium will be worse with better tools.